# How to synchronize with jasmine.execute?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, jasmine

I am using jasmine as a lib in my project and I've been looking around the [jasmine node js docs](https://jasmine.github.io/setup/nodejs.html) on how to synchronize `jasmine.execute` with the rest of my code but, since `execute` returns `undefined` (and not a `Promise` as I would expect), it's not clear to me how to synchornize with the execution and perform some action only **after** jasmine finishes the execution.

So for example, in code below, how can I execute `doSomething()` only after jasmine finishes?

```
var Jasmine = require('jasmine');
var jasmine = new Jasmine();

jasmine.loadConfig({
    spec_dir: 'spec',
    spec_files: [
        'someTest.js',
    ]
});

jasmine.execute();

doSomething(); // is done before jasmine finishes
```

Is there a way to synchronize with the execution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can synchronize with the execution by making use of the `onComplete` event that jasmine provides.

Basically you need to create and fulfill a promise in the `onComplete` callback.

Here's a sample code:

```
var Jasmine = require('jasmine');
var jasmine = new Jasmine();

jasmine.loadConfig({
    spec_dir: 'spec',
    spec_files: [
        'someTest.js',
    ]
});

var executeJasmine = new Promise( (resolve,reject) => {
    jasmine.execute();
    jasmine.onComplete(function(status) {
        // status is true if all specs are passed
        // false otherwise
        resolve(status);
    });

});

executeJasmine().then((passed) => {
    // code that gets executed only AFTER jasmine finishes execution
    doSomething();

    if(passed) {
        console.log('All specs have passed');
    }
    else {
        console.log('At least one spec has failed');
    }
})
```